# Globally update color for navbarbutton items

Tags: ios, swift, navbar

I have globally updated the color of the tabBarItems by applying the following in the App Delegate file:

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .black
```

Is it possible to do the same but to apply the changes to the navBarButton items? The solutions I am finding are for iOS 4 or 5.

Comment: What about `UIBarButtonItem.appearance()`?

Comment: It would be better if you specify what exactly you want to customize in buttons and which buttons you want to customize since approaches could be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To globally change the appeariance change it in `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
var navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.black
navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = UIColor.blue
// Item title color
navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
```